# iPad Orientation/Frame size problem

Tags: ipad, ios4, orientation

In "View Did Load" I'm trying to determine the size of the view so I can appropriately size a subview.  I want it to always stretch about the length and width of the screen regardless of orientation.

```
quest *anview = [[quest alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-100, self.view.frame.size.height-100)];
self.aquest=anview;
```

But this always returns a width of 748 and a height of 1024 when it should return the opposite when I'm in landscape.  I know that you can't get orientation on the simulator but this occurs on the device as well.  When I get the orientation:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
NSLog(@"device orientation:%d",orientation);
```

I correctly get the orientation but this log statement returns the 748/1024 regardless of orientation.

```
    NSLog(@"size w:%f",self.view.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"size h:%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Anyone know what's going on?  Does this have to do with me putting this in the viewdidLoad method? Should I put it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use the *bounds* property instead of *frame*.

The view is always created in portrait mode and then rotated, even if you launch the application in landscape. You should be able to keep the subview stretched by setting its size relative to the parent's portrait size and the autorsizing mask to *UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight*, providing the *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:* return YES for the right device orientation. It will also keep the distance from the top and left margin unless you add to the mask a different *UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleMargin*.